# How to viewing selected calendar events for selected calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-chrome, android

I have been trying to use the Google Calendar web app in an intuitive fashion.

Below is a screenshot of what appears when I log in from my Android phone using Chrome for Android.

Consider that on the given page there are no entries from the calendar named Family, nor from the calendar named Celebrations.

I want to see what is in these calendars.

In order to do this, I would like to be able to select an option next to each calendar, to view the consecutive list of events just for the selected calendars, skipping all blank spaces/dates where nothing happens, but I don't know how to do this.

Can someone please help me?

[image: Google Calendar]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the **Week** view, use the **Schedule** view. Ref. [View your day, week, or month](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110849?hl=en).

---

The screenshot doesn't look like the default view of Google Calendar when it's opened in Google Chrome for Android. You have checked the **Desktop site** option in the Chrome menu.

As you can see, Google Calendar doesn't show all the elements properly when working this way.

The screenshot shows a button with the text **Settisemana** (Week). This button is the view selector. There should be an option for **Schedule**. You should find how Google has translated this option into the Language you use in Google Calendar.

If this view doesn't meet your needs, try unchecking **Desktop site** on the Chrome menu.

Another option is to install the Google Calendar app for Android or sync a Calendar app for Android with your Google Account so that you have a better experience.